# Solving algebra equations in python

Tags: python, equation, algebra

I'm new to programming and I'm having a hard time solving this equation using Python.
I would like for the system to give me the value for X. 
((X-5)/(2) + (X/4) + (X-12)/(3))

Comment: This is an awfully difficult program for a beginner, I would choose something simpler if I were you.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an `=` in that expression. `X` can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

[Sympy](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/sympy.html) looks promising, especially [section 3.2.4, "Equation Solving"](https://scipy-lectures.org/packages/sympy.html#equation-solving).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your right hand side of equation is some given value or expression:

```
import sympy as sym
x = sym.Symbol("x")
RHS = 13
LHS = (x - 5)/2 + x/4 + (x - 12)/3
eqn = LHS - RHS
soln = sym.solve(eqn, x)
print(soln)
```

This yields the solution x = 18. Replace RHS with your own value or expression. If there is nothing, simply put RHS to be 0; which gives the solution x = 6.

If you want to solve your equation step by step, you are still going to need SymPy:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html